# How do I merge GWT Permutations from different Locales?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, locale

I define the following locale in my module xml file:

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="en, en_US, en_GB"/>
<extend-property name="locale" values="de, de_DE" />
```

**How can I get only one permutation for en, en_US, en_GB and one permutation for de, de_DE?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the country-specific versions, if you do not offer them as options to your users:

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="en"/>
<extend-property name="locale" values="de" />
```

To set the default locale:

```
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en"/>
```

Comment: and create property provider that translates en_whatever to en, de_whatever to de

Comment: @Maciej - There is no need to do that if `_en` and `_de` properties files are already present.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin So do I need property provider for en_US, en_... to get the en? ANother question how do I overwrite the default?

Comment: @MaciejChałapuk So do I need property provider for en_US, en_... to get the en? Another question how do I overwrite the default?

Comment: If you have a property file for `_en`, then you don't need a property file for `en_US` if you don't plan to use that locale as a separate permutation.

Comment: You cannot overwrite the default locale. You can set it to one of the locales that you plan to offer. It will still be a separate permutation.

Comment: IMO collapse-property is a better approach.

Answer (score 7):

The GWT way to merge permutations of different property values is called [SoftPermutations](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/SoftPermutations):

```
<collapse-property name="locale" values="en, en_US, en_GB" />   
<collapse-property name="locale" values="de, de_DE" />
```

EDITED

About the benefits of using all locales instead of selecting one per language,  you take advantage of using all of those languages differences, what is very important for users.

Think that GWT includes a full i18n stack (based on [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/)) for internationalising numbers, dates, plurals, etc. and it is not the same to show an ['en' date-picker](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html?locale=en#!CwDatePicker) vs an ['en_GB' datepicker](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html?locale=en_GB#!CwDatePicker) because Europeans use Monday as first day of week instead of Sunday.

The increment of javascript in your final permutation is not significant (very few KB), because only those slim differences have to be included, since most of the properties are shared between similar languages.

Of course you only have to translate your application once per language supported, for instance you write all your application messages in 'en' because 'en_GB' will fallback to 'en' when a message is not found, but you still maintain the option to change some messages if you need it.

What many people do with locale in GWT is to collapse all of them avoiding permutation explosion `<collapse-property name="locale" values="*" />` and improving compilation times. You have the option to put that line out when you deliver your app for production which normally happens once per delivering cycle, and you can leave your CI server compiling all permutations.

Comment: What are the benefits of specifying three locales and telling the compiler to collapse them in one, as opposed to specifying only one locale that you need?

Comment: Good question. Yes what are the benefits?

Comment: With one locale in one permutation, the app can only be used in one language. With three locales in one permutation, the app can be used in any of those three languages, but only one permutation is emitted. This makes the compile time shorter, but the total downloaded by the user larger. If you only want one locale, then of course collapsing other useless (to you) locales would be silly, but if you need all of them, skipping other locales will limit who can use your app.

Comment: @ColinAlworth the increment of JS collapsing similar locales is insignificant, since gwt will reuse common things. Updated my answer to explain the benefits.

Comment: This is a good solution but only if a user is given an option to choose `en_GB` locale, for example. Otherwise, if this locale is never set in an app, declaring it and then collapsing it will increase the file size, but users will never benefit from those extra kB.

Comment: Of course if you dont use a concrete locale like any other property, dont define it to avoid compilation. But in the question the user ask for using those locales: `en, en_US, en_GB`, he don't set any other like `en_CA, en_IN ...`